# Inputting a value into a new command gives error

Tags: macros, tkz-euclide

So I'm trying to pass in a value into a new command called `circleFig`. However, the compiler keeps trying to insert `pt` in front of it, essentially breaking the code. How can I force the compiler to treat the input as a real number, and not what it wants to perceive it as?

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\newcommand{\circleFig}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/P, 3/0/R}
    \tkzDrawCircle[line width=0.1pt](O,P)
    
    \foreach \i in {0,...,#1 - 1}
    {
        \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=360*\i /#1 ,center=O,radius=3]
        \tkzGetPoint{P}
        \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=360*\i /#1 + 360/#1,center=O,radius=3]
        \tkzGetPoint{R}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20!white, line join=round, line width=0.1pt](O,P,R)
    }
    \tkzLabelPoints(O)
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
    \circleFig{3}
\end{document}
```

and this is the terrible error I got.

````
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.20     \circleFig{3}
                      
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.20     \circleFig{3}
                      
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.20     \circleFig{3}
                      
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Missing character: There is no - in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 20.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 20.
[1```
````

Answer (score 2):

You need to "tell" the `\foreach`-statement to evaluate the upper bound via `\pgfmathparse`—do:
`\foreach \i [parse=true] in {0,...,#1-1}`

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\newcommand{\circleFig}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O, 3/0/P, 3/0/R}
    \tkzDrawCircle[line width=0.1pt](O,P)
    
    \foreach \i [parse=true] in {0,...,#1-1}
    {
        \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=360*\i /#1 ,center=O,radius=3]
        \tkzGetPoint{P}
        \tkzDefPointOnCircle[angle=360*\i /#1 + 360/#1,center=O,radius=3]
        \tkzGetPoint{R}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=blue!20!white, line join=round, line width=0.1pt](O,P,R)
    }
    \tkzLabelPoints(O)
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\begin{document}
    \circleFig{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But you still get another error-message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
[...]
Class standalone:
Output written on test.png.
) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 2 was incomplete)
```

I think this is a bug in standalone.